# Remote File Read & Write operation

Tags: java, file

I have .txt file in my remote system for eg: ip = 172.16.20.1
path is /etc/config

how do i need to connect to this file from java

here is my code.

```
String path = "http://172.16.20.1/etc/config/file.txt";

URL url = new URL(path);
URLConnection yc = url.openConnection();
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader (yc.getInputStream()));
```

but m getting file not exception when i use path with http & getting javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException if i use https

M i missing something This file file.txt is in /etc folder (Linux)

Comment: M geeting file not found exception

Comment: getting java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused,if i use FTP protocol

Answer (score 0):

Check this for reading a file from remote machine using commons-vfs,its working fine

```
public static void readRemoteManifestFile( String ipAddress,String filePath,String username,String password ){

    //filePath="/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/abc/test/NavigationPanel.html";

    try {

        StandardFileSystemManager manager = new StandardFileSystemManager();
        manager.init();

        FileObject remoteFile = manager.resolveFile(createConnectionString(ipAddress, username,password,
                filePath), createDefaultOptions());
        if(!remoteFile.exists()){
            System.out.println( filePath+": no such file" );
        }else{
            Reader      inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(  remoteFile.getContent().getInputStream());
            char c;
              int i;
            while((i=inputStreamReader.read())!=-1)
             {
                // int to character
                c=(char)i;            
                // print char
                System.out.println("Character Read: "+c);
             }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println( "Failed to read for "+
                filePath+": "+e);
        System.out.println( "Failed to read for "+
                filePath+": "+e.getMessage());

    }


}
public static String createConnectionString(String hostName,
        String username, String password, String remoteFilePath) {
    return "sftp://" + username + ":" + password + "@" + hostName + "/" + remoteFilePath;
}

public static FileSystemOptions createDefaultOptions()
        throws FileSystemException {
    FileSystemOptions opts = new FileSystemOptions();
    SftpFileSystemConfigBuilder.getInstance().setStrictHostKeyChecking(
            opts, "no");
    SftpFileSystemConfigBuilder.getInstance().setUserDirIsRoot(opts, false);
    SftpFileSystemConfigBuilder.getInstance().setTimeout(opts, 10000);
    return opts;
}
```

}